# How to draw a semi-transparent rectangle on Panel containing some user controls in it?

Tags: c#

I want to draw a semi-transparent rectangle on panel containing some user controls in it.

My main goal is to create selection rectangle similar to what the windows file explorer does.

And tried with `Control.Paint` Event but the rectangle shows **beneath** the user control. I want that semi-transparent rectangle to show **on top** of all controls present in the panel.

Here is what I tried:

```
    class test
    {
    public FlowLayoutPanel flp;
    public test()
    {
    flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    flp.Controls.Add(c);//Here c is User Control
    flp.Paint += (s, pe) =>
            {
                Rectangle f = new Rectangle();
                f.Size = new Size(100, 100);

                Brush b = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(25, Color.Red));
                pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, f);
                b.Dispose();
            };
    }
    }
```

Here Rectangle is visible under the user control.

Comment: besides missing heaps of information, like what are you using, and what are you drawing on, have you tried setting the z order ?

Comment: @Noctis Drawing a rectangle on top of panel with some user controls in it.And how to add z-order to the drawing rectangle

Comment: If you are using winforms this is not really possible as you can't have (semi-)transparent overlapping controls. You can overlay with a form though, but it will get in the way hen the user wants to interact. If you only want a single color you could add it in the paint events of all controls..

Comment: @TaW My main goal is to create a windows file explorer selection rectangle like one

Comment: I have added a tested solution and even played a little with using it as a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using a 2nd Form to overlay the selection.

[image]

I am using a `TabPage tabPage5` as my container, you should be able to adapt to any other Control or even the whole Form..

I use two class level variables and prepare the overlay Form somwhere at the start..:

```
Form overlay = new Form();
Point m_Down = Point.Empty;

void prepareOverlay()
{
    overlay.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;  // your selection color
    overlay.Opacity = 0.2f;             // tranparency
    overlay.MinimizeBox = false;        // prepare..
    overlay.MaximizeBox = false;
    overlay.Text = "";
    overlay.ShowIcon = false;
    overlay.ControlBox = false;
    overlay.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    overlay.Size = Size.Empty;
    overlay.TopMost = true;
}
```

These events are needed for the parent container the user will drag over:

```
private void tabPage5_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    m_Down = e.Location;  
    overlay.Size = Size.Empty; 
    overlay.Show();
}

private void tabPage5_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        overlay.Location = tabPage5.PointToScreen(m_Down);
        overlay.Size = new Size(e.X - m_Down.X, e.Y - m_Down.Y);
    }
}

private void tabPage5_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // do your stuff and then hide overlay..
    overlay.Hide();
}
```

I have only coded for the standard case of a user dragging from the top left to the bottom right.

For the other cases you will need to do a little juggling with `Math.Abs`& `Math.Min`, calculating the `Size` in absolutes and using the coordinate minima for the `Location`..

To collect all covered Controls you will have to revert the `overlay.Bounds` to the client coordinates using `selectionRect = tabPage5.RectangleToClient (overlay.Bounds);` To collect nested Controls the selection could use a method like this one:

```
List<Control> controlSelection = new List<Control>();

List<Control> getControls(Control container, Rectangle rect)
{
    controlSelection = new List<Control>();
    foreach (Control ctl in container.Controls)
        if (rect.Contains(ctl.Bounds))
        {
            controlSelection.Add(ctl);
            foreach (Control ct in ctl.Controls) controlSelection.Add(ct); ;
        }
    return controlSelection;
}
```

To call it use:

```
Rectangle grabRect = tabPage5.RectangleToClient (overlay.Bounds);
controlSelection =  getControls(tabPage5, grabRect);
Console.WriteLine(controlSelection.Count + " Controls grabbed.");
```

For multiple levels of nesting you will need a recursive function! For this case it may be better to leave the `selectionRectangle` is screen coordinates and to transform the tested controls' bound to screen as well..

And, of course it is up to you to decide if a selection must **just hi**t (`Rectangle.IntersectsWith()`) or **cover** the targets completely; I have coded the latter (`Rectangle.Contains()`).

Answer (score 0):

Child controls are always drawn after the parent control is drawn, so they will always show on top of anything you paint on the parent.

You will need to create a semi transparent child control and make sure the z-index of that child control is higher than the other controls.

**Edit:** This solution is not possible in WinForms. Or at least not with the standard controls.

In frameworks where this is possible, the control on top will likely block mouse and touch events from coming through.

Comment: I may have been a little hasty in my answer. In WinForms, which you seem to be using, it's not possible. At least not with the standard controls. And even if it were, this method causes other problems, such as not being able to click on the control below.

Answer (score 0):

I took the awesome code, from the answer above and been tweaking it. Made it so you can move the mouse in any direction and it'll draw & size the form accordingly. I confine the overlay, to the inside of the parent form. This is still a work, in progress.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form overlay;

    bool a, b;

    int c, d, f, g;

    Point ptNope, ptHold, ptTest, ptDown = Point.Empty;

    List<Control> controlSelection = new List<Control>();

    List<Control> getControls(Control container, Rectangle rect)
    {
        rect = RectangleToClient(rect);

        controlSelection = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control ctl in container.Controls)
            if (rect.Contains(ctl.Bounds))
            {
                controlSelection.Add(ctl);
                foreach (Control ct in ctl.Controls) controlSelection.Add(ct);
            }

        return controlSelection;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        overlay = new Form()
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            BackColor = Color.Fuchsia,
            Opacity = 0.2f,
            TopMost = true
        };
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ptNope.X = this.Left; ptNope.Y = this.Top;
        ptDown = e.Location;
        overlay.Show();
    }

    public static int vise(int value, int min, int max) { return (value < min) ? min : (value > max) ? max : value; }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ptHold = PointToScreen(ptDown);
            ptTest = PointToScreen(e.Location);

            a = (ptTest.X < ptHold.X); b = (ptTest.Y < ptHold.Y);

            c = a ? ptTest.X : ptHold.X; c = vise(c, ptNope.X, ptNope.X + this.Width);
            d = b ? ptTest.Y : ptHold.Y; d = vise(d, ptNope.Y, ptNope.Y + this.Height);
            f = a ? (ptHold.X - ptTest.X) : (ptTest.X - ptHold.X); f = vise(f, 0, a ? (ptHold.X - ptNope.X) : ((ptNope.X + this.Width) - ptHold.X));
            g = b ? (ptHold.Y - ptTest.Y) : (ptTest.Y - ptHold.Y); g = vise(g, 0, b ? (ptHold.Y - ptNope.Y) : ((ptNope.Y + this.Height) - ptHold.Y));

            overlay.Left = c; overlay.Top = d; overlay.Width = f; overlay.Height = g;

            controlSelection = getControls(this, Bounds);
            foreach (Control c in controlSelection) { c.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; }

            controlSelection = getControls(this, overlay.Bounds);
            foreach (Control c in controlSelection) { c.BackColor = Color.Fuchsia; }

            label1.Text = controlSelection.Count + " Control(s) grabbed";
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        overlay.Hide(); label1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Thoughts and ideas, for improvement are welcome.