# C# - how to get list of textboxes with same tag value in windowform?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have several `TextBox`es on form. I have assigned them the *same* `Tag` value. Now I want to access and *sum up* values of these `TextBox`es. I have tried the following but it didn't work. Even it didn't throw any exception. But the control exit from the function before *foreach loop*. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
private void CalculateExpense()
{
    int sum = 0;

    var textBoxes = this.Controls
      .OfType<TextBox>()
      .Where(d => d.Tag.ToString() == "ExpenseField")
      .ToList();

    foreach (var item in textBoxes)
    {
        sum = sum + Convert.ToInt16(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text) ? item.Text : "0");
    }

    this.TotalExpenseLbl.Text = sum.ToString();
    this.TotalMonthlyExpenses.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to debug your code and check if `textBoxes` is not empty?

Comment: a) are the tboxes directly on the form or in some container, e,g, groupbox or panel? What does the debugger say about `textBoxes.Count` etc.. - If they are nested and you know where replace `this.Controls` by `the container.Controls`. If they are in many containers you may want to look into a [recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022010/how-to-draw-a-semi-transparent-rectangle-on-panel-containing-some-user-controls/32023219#32023219)..

Comment: ` I have tried the following but it didn't work` can you ellaborate how it didnt work?

Comment: All the text boxes are placed in different group boxes. When I debug the code, the debugger exist from the code block when it reaches 
 var textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(d => d.Tag.ToString() == "ExpenseField").ToList();

Comment: Huh?? Do you tell us it skips the last two lines??

Comment: It skips all the code from loop to end of method body.

Comment: @mubsher This is unlikely to happen.

Comment: I've also put the null check in loop body when casting the textbox value. @SeM

Comment: _"All the text boxes are placed in different group boxes"_ - in which case you need ro use a recursive search or something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button#3426721) to find them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the `TextBox`es are *directly* on the form and not within *containers* (`Panel`s, `GroupBox`es etc).

```
int sum = Controls
  .OfType<TextBox>()
  .Where(box => string.Equals("ExpenseField", box.Tag as String))
  .Select(box => int.TryParse(box.Text, out var v) ? v : 0)
  .Sum(); 

this.TotalExpenseLbl.Text = sum.ToString();
this.TotalMonthlyExpenses.Text = sum.ToString();
```

It seems, that the main problem in your code is in `d.Tag.ToString()` since `Tag` is `null` by default.

**Edit**: in case `TextBox`es are within several *containes*, you have to use recursion instead of `Controls` collection:

```
private static IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control) {
  var controls = control.Controls.OfType<Control>();

  return controls
    .SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl))
    .Concat(controls);
}

...

int sum = GetAll(this)
  .OfType<TextBox>()
  .Where(box => string.Equals("ExpenseField", box.Tag as String))
  .Select(box => int.TryParse(box.Text, out var v) ? v : 0)
  .Sum(); 

this.TotalExpenseLbl.Text = sum.ToString();
this.TotalMonthlyExpenses.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. It makes my code work but I'm getting 0 as sum.May be because  they are in different groupboxes.

Comment: @mubsher: Then (if `TextBox`es are in different containers) you should chnage `Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` into recursive version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button