# C#: How to use a Button (f.e., or even other objects) if I only have its name?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I mean, all button names I have are like "btActionXX", being 'XX' 2 numbers taked from Row and Column from a Matrix. For this numbers, I have strings like:

```
string btName = "btAction";
string ending = "01";
```

Is there some way to use ' "btName" + ending ' (parsed "btAction01") to use properties from a Button named as this? Something like `Button.fromName("btName"+ending);` (this not works) that returns a Button object, or somthing like this?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF or some other GUI framework?

Comment: I think this is something you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)

Comment: @phuzi from the information provided, how do you know it is WPF related?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! -

Comment: Winforms: If you are really looking for the Name property and not the varaiblename yopu can either use a controls.Where linq to search for typeof Button and Name= yourname or you can use a [recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022010/how-to-draw-a-semi-transparent-rectangle-on-panel-containing-some-user-controls/32023219#32023219) to collect all controls. Note that dynamically created controls do by default not have a Name set and also the Name is not unique. Example: `var btns = yourParentContainer.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name == yourName);`

Comment: Sorry, this is for Windows Forms.

Comment: @TaW Okey this can works. I'll try this way as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this thread:
[Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)
There is API method called Find. Quote from the Microsoft documentation:
"Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of all the controls that match."
I think this is what you're looking for.